# Django i18n, using template inside python string, how to translate

Tags: django, templates, internationalization

I need to translate some emails in a django app and I was wondering what is the best way to tag for translation something like this:

```py
subject_template = (
        'Enlèvement programmé le {{ pickup_date }} {{ pickup.timeslot }} - {{ pickup.display_id }}'
    )
```

This is a part on an email in a pythons script, however template are used inside the string, so I cannot really use gettext isn't it ?

Maybe one of you ended up in a similar situation, if you have a solution that would be neat.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is many ways to making this.

Personally, I prefer to store in html format the templates of the emails that I need to send and I generate the rendering in the back before sending them.

You can use a package like django-anymail: https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail.

Or making your own function by using the render functionnality of django:
some documentation about using the template engine of django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system

But you can use the render_to_string function provided by framework:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
t = render_to_string("mail/template.html")
```

For your question about using gettext, you can use gettext in your case of course. Probably not very easy for big email:

```
subject_template = (
        gettext(f'Enlèvement programmé le {pickup_date} {pickup.timeslot} - {pickup.display_id}')
    )
```